Laravel / livewire dispatched event not triggering
Yet another post for an event not working, but have read through the docs and cannot make sense as I'm right now just trying to replicate the basic example.
I have 3 components:
Parent: Beat-create
it has 2 child components:
BeatScore and BeatPlayer
this is beatscore
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class BeatCreate extends Component
{

    public $beat_times = [
        ['label'=>'1/4 note','value'=>'4n'],
        ['label'=>'1/8 note','value'=>'8n'],
        ['label'=>'1/16 note','value'=>'16n']
    ];
    public $type_exercise = 1; /*1 = beat, 2 = fill*/
    public $note_type = '8n';
    public $difficulty = 1;
    public $scores = [
        'snare'=>[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'kick'=>[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'hat'=>[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'ride'=>[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'tom1'=>[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'tom2'=>[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'tom3'=>[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'crash'=>[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ];
    public function render()
    {
        
        return view('livewire.beat-create');
    }
    public function updateScore($instrument, $beat)
    {
        $this->scores[$instrument][$beat] ^=1;
        $this->dispatch('score-updated',data:['scores'=>$this->scores,
                        'difficulty'=>$this-> difficulty,
                        'note-type'=>$this->note_type]
    );
}
}

and Beat Player
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use livewire\Attributes\On;

class BeatPlayer extends Component
{
    public $scores;
    public $difficulty;
    public $note_type;

    // public function mount($score)
    // {
    //     $this->score = $score;
    // }
    
    #[On('score-updated')]
    public function handleUpates($updates){
        Log::debug("listeing");
        dd($updates);
    }
    public function updateScore($scores)
    {
        $this->scores = $scores;
    }
    public function updateDifficulty($difficulty){
        $this->difficulty=$difficulty;
    }
    public function updateNoteType($note_type)
    {
        $this->note_type = $note_type;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        // dd($this);
        return view('livewire.beat-player');
    }
}

I can confirm the code for dispatching the event is triggered ( through dd as Log::debug gives me an error...) also confirm the components are loaded.
but the handleUpdates function never gets called.
What am I missing?

Very dumb mistake in my part
use Livewire\Component;
- use livewire\Attributes\On;
+ use Livewire\Attributes\On;


no errors were being thrown, so I have to figure that out.
